# Prevent Putty from wrapping lines

Tags: windows, putty

When a line is longer than the current window width, Putty will wrap the line instead of showing a horizontal scroll bar. How can I prevent this behavior?

It's particularly annoying when using a MySQL client.

Comment: I also find http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/horiz-scroll.html . Does this mean that it's not possible.

Comment: what if you choose   http://i.stack.imgur.com/RiG58.png then http://www.installsetupconfig.com/win32programming/puttyreactosdebug_files/debugserialputtyreactos045.png  as described here http://www.ehow.com/how_8693034_prevent-line-wrap-putty.html

Comment: I have already tried that. As mentioned in the documentation, it overwrite the beginning of the long line.

Answer (score 4):

PuTTY, as noted, does not provide a horizontal scroll bar.  It supports the VT100-style autowrap feature which may be confused for the ability to suppress line-wrapping.  But it does not work that way:

- applications running in a terminal generally use terminal descriptions (in termcap or terminfo format) to know how the terminal will behave.
- for instance, these *capabilities* are listed in the [terminfo(5)](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html) manual page.
- the terminal descriptions include strings used by ncurses and other applications to *initialize* the terminal.
- PuTTY's configuration dialog provides several features which can change *its* notion of the initial state.
- a "complete" initialization string from the host (which does not make assumptions about the terminal's initial state) will override PuTTY's *initial state*.

The feature in terminfo is called "auto-margins", and is listed [here](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html#h3-Predefined-Capabilities):

```
   auto_right_margin         am     am   terminal has auto-
                                         matic margins
```

In *[Basic Capabilities](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html#h3-Basic-Capabilities)*, the manual notes

> If the terminal wraps around to the
>   beginning  of the next line when it reaches the right margin, then it should have the **am** capability.

That is, it tells the application what to *expect*.  If the application does not expect that the terminal will wrap it will assume that it does not, and move the cursor to simulate wrapping as needed.

As a general rule, terminal emulators provide configurable features that can be

- put into an initial state
- enabled
- disabled

The last (disabled) is much less common than the first two.  PuTTY's automargin feature lies in the first category.  As noted in *[PuTTY wish horiz-scroll](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/horiz-scroll.html)*, if you really need horizontal scrolling, you will only get that by using an application running in the terminal emulator which simulates the feature.  The example given ([less](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/index.html)) provides this using the `-S` option (see *[Use `less -S` for horizontal scrolling](http://heyrod.com/snippet/s/less-chop-long-lines.html)*).